# Descargar pagina web o html completa

Tags: javascript, html, descargar

es la primera vez que realizo una consulta en el foro.
Estoy creado una pequeña app web, que me permita agregar contendido de manera dinámica (texto e imágenes) para luego descargar ese contendido y poder enviar el html descargado por mail.

La app web funciona como una especie de lista de tareas de manera local, hasta acá todo perfecto.
El problema es que después que descargo el sitio web, apretando el botón derecho del mouse y eligiendo la opción "guardar como", los links absolutos que utilicé como fuente de las imágenes, se convierten en relativos y por ende cuando mando ese html por mail, quien lo recibe no ve la imagen.

Pensé en copiar todo el código fuente en lugar de descargarlo o de buscar una forma de descargar el código fuente desde javascript. Pero por el momento no encontré la manera de hacerlo.

Esto es lo que he intentado para copiar el código fuente

```
   function copiar(){
var codigoACopiar = document;
var seleccion = document.createRange();
seleccion.selectNodeContents(codigoACopiar);
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(seleccion);
var res = document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeRange(seleccion);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar **document.documentElement.innerHTML** si deseas editar y/o ver el código fuente de algún sitio web actual.

```js
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true';
document.designMode='on'; 
void 0;
javascript:alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

O puedes usar [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) en caso de un sitio web externo:

```js
const URL = 'https://www.sap.com/belgique/index.html';
fetch(URL)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => {
    console.log(text);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```